# Specifing a timeout wait when sending an APDU to a smartcard on windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, nfc, smartcard, smartcard-reader, contactless-smartcard

I'm using the `windows.devices.smartcards` namespace to transmit APDUs to smartcards on the Windows Phone 8.1 (silverlight) platform over NFC.

I'm using the `TransmitAsync` method on the `SmartCardConnection` class to send an APDU and wait for it's response:

```
responseBuf = await scConn.TransmitAsync(writer.DetachBuffer());
```

Most commands are working well, but one such command is taking much longer than others (2.5 secs), and craps out with an exception

> A device attached to the system is not functioning

I've tried to use the `Wait()` method on the `Task` class but this doesn't have any effect. It seems to me that the lower level smartcard libraries are faulting the request i.e. the `Wait` on the `Task` is not being honoured.

Is there a direct way to control the response timeout behaviour when communicating with smartcards over NFC?